# Reading *ptw files into Mathematica

Tags: list-manipulation, import

I have a SWIR camera that outputs raw image files in *ptw format.  I need to read them into Mathematica for image analysis.  I know that such files can be read into Matlab and C++, so there must be a way of reading them into Mathematica as well.

thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica SE. To get started:1) take [the introductory tour now](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour),2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up [by clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge,3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking checkmark sign](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work),4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.